# Differentiability Of Modulus Of Function

Tags: calculus

Consider a differentiable function $f(x)$ such that $f(x)=0$ whenever $f'(x)=0$ then does it imply that $|f(x)|$ is differentiable? Why or Why Not??
$$$$If any such function takes the value $0$ at two point say $x_1$ and $x_2$ then $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=0$ then by Rolle's Theorem we have $f'(x_0)=0$ where $x_1<x_0<x_2$ and hence ATQ $f(x_0)=0$ again applying Rolle's Theorem on $[x_1, x_0]$ and $[x_0, x_2]$ we will get that $f(x)=0$ on infinitely many points.
$$$$Plz Help Me

Comment: Do you mean "$f'(x)=0$ whenever $f(x)=0$"? As stated, $f(x)=x$ is a counterexample.

Comment: $f(x) = x$ will vacuously be a counterexample

Comment: No I mean $f(x)=0$ whenever $f'(x)=0$

Comment: Then in that case, the statement is false, as Greg and I mentioned. And $f(x) = x$ is a counterexample

Comment: But in the case of $f(x)=x$, $f'(x)$ is never equal to $0$ but I want a function $f(x)$ which takes the value $0$ at least two times

Comment: Then modify your function just a bit by making some translated copy of what $x \mapsto x$ does near the origin.

Answer (score 1):

$$x \mapsto x$$ is a counterexample since $$x \mapsto |x|$$

is not differentiable in $0$.